# Apache MatchRedirect exception regex

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, regex, regular-expressions

I want to redirect any URL that is Https and hasn't start with "system_" to the same URL with http.

for exapmle for this url :

```
https://exsite.tld/some/thing/that/not/start/with/pattern
```

to :

```
http://exsite.tld/some/thing/that/not/start/with/pattern
```

but this url:

```
https://exsite.tld/system_aas3f4
```

Shouldn't redirect.

I try:

```
  RedirectMatch  ^/?((?!(system_)).*)  http://exsite.tld/$1
```

but it won't work. I don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use rewrite instead. Try something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/system_
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://exsite.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

ought to do it. Please test it before implementing in live environment.

What these rules state is: 1. enable rewrite engine, 2. check if HTTPS is on, 3. check if the URI path does not start with `system_`. If *both* the above two conditions are true, do the rewrite to http version of your domain for all remaining URIs.